# Android : Should android bundle be used as a dto

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, android-bundle

It is a common practice to use POJO's or DTOs for modeling the data from an api or a data source. For these models, you have to right a serialization/de-serialization logic or use a library like gson to do the same.

I was wondering if we can use a Bundle as a dto in android since it already is being used for passing around data between fragments and activities. Bundle essentially is a wrapper over a hash map, so we can put/get any data in it.

Is it a good practice to use Bundles as the DTO in your android app? What are the advantages/disadvantages of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Is it a good practice to use Bundles as the DTO in your android app?`

No, it's not. `Bundle` is a `final class` ,therefore you may not expand your own taxonomy to adapt e reuse code for the domain of your problem.

`What are the advantages/disadvantages of this approach?`

- Advantages:

  - A built-in android object that implements `Parcelable` instead of regular `Serializable`(faster serialization).
- Disavantages:

  - It's a `final class`.
  - You have no control or power of decision over how it will treat any data inside.
  - Data types limitation.
  - Poor abstraction.
  - Not scalable.
  - Meant for communication only between activities or services. So you may not have control of its lifecycle nor the management of its references, if you ever need to.

Comment: One problem i am currently encountering with this approach is that i never know what data is present inside an object at any time so debugging is very hard

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle` is essentially `HashMap`. Also, you wouldn't want to put big size data in a `Bundle` because it will significantly slow down opening `Activities` if you use such `Bundle` as an `Intent` data.

`HashMap` in itself is a low-level data abstraction. You may want to construct your DTO around a `HashMap` but it's an implementation detail.